# https page is returning "Empty Response" in Chrome

Tags: facebook, ssl, response

I have a facebook app; as you know, facebook requires ssl certificates for app pages.

I've bought my SSL certificate from Godaddy. When I try to reach my app, it tries to access my https page but **most of the time** page takes very long time to load and then returns empty response error.

I am dealing with this problem **most of the time** and in **only chrome**, firefox and ie just works fine.

Is there any others who deal with this problem? How can I solve it?